# Localization of a WPF app and Localization of CodeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I am using following Localization option: [Click](http://codinginfinity.me/post/2015-05-10/localization_of_a_wpf_app_the_simple_approach)

Code Localization.cs:

```
public class TranslationSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ResourceManager _rm = new ResourceManager("RECOVER.Languages.Language",
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    private CultureInfo _currentCulture;

    private static TranslationSource _instance;

    public static TranslationSource Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new TranslationSource();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get { return _rm.GetString(key, _currentCulture); }
    }

    public CultureInfo CurrentCulture
    {
        get { return _currentCulture; }
        set
        {
            _currentCulture = value;
            var @event = PropertyChanged;
            if (@event != null)
            {
                @event.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class LocExtension : Binding
{
    public LocExtension(string name) : base("[" + name + "]")
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        Source = TranslationSource.Instance;
    }
}
```

How use the same principle also for Localizate CodeBehind? To translate some strings in selected language (MessageBox etc.).

Thanks for helping! If any question please ask

Maybe so?

```
ResourceManager _rm = new ResourceManager("RECOVER.Languages.Language", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            var kekssda = _rm.GetString("Button", TranslationSource.Instance.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Use resource files (resource.resx), then you can have localised ones (resource.en-US.resx, resource.fr-FR.resx, etc.) and have .NET handle it all for you.

Comment: I update my post. It is so correct? Or how you imagine this?

Comment: Hey @Ruker, do you already have a solution for your problem, or are you still active in this thread?

Answer (score 1):

In your project you create your localized resource files (e.g., Resources.resx, Resources.en-US.resx, Resources.en-UK.resx) in some folder as example "*YourProjectRoot/Resources/Strings/Resources.en-US*". Note that Resources.resx is the default resource file. The ResourceManager will handel these different localized files for you just by define the location:

```
private readonly ResourceManager _rm = Resources.Strings.Resources.ResourceManager
```

To use the same principle in the codebehind, you need to use the `TranslationSource` to get localized values, it is the connection beween the ResourceManager and the actual CultureInfo.

There you are implementing `public string this[string key] {...}` this can be used in your code:

```
var text = TranslationSource.Instance["news"];
```